# remove string style=";" with special char in it fom sql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, replace, phpmyadmin

how can I remove all occurrences of these two strings with special char in them?

**style=";"**

**style="; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;"**

I know this works to remove the semicolon.

```
UPDATE oc_product_description SET description = REPLACE(description, char(59),'');
```

but I need to do for the above sets of text to remove only occurrences as they are above or they will upset the good occurrences in the database if u just remove the ; first I lose other occurrences that I need to keep.

I removed all the style code from within the tag now I am left with the above to get rid of from the database product description.

there are 50,000 descriptions so manually is out of the question.

Thanks in advance for any help. and much appreciated in every way for it.

Comment: What's special about `;`? You can just type it as-is in your query, I don't think there's even a keyboard layout that omits it.

Comment: No #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''style=")' at line 1. the ; breaks the SQL as it ends the line early.

Comment: So you're trying to workaround a bug in PhpMyAdmin I guess.

Comment: I guess that's what is it.

Comment: I've just tried PhpAdmin at https://demo.phpmyadmin.net and query editor is indeed terrible. It's so bad that it's barely usable. Why this piece of software seems to be so popular is beyond my comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE` to replace a string with another string (not just a char)

So something like

```
UPDATE oc_product_description SET description = REPLACE(description, 'style=";"','');

UPDATE oc_product_description SET description = REPLACE(description, 'style="; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;"','');
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''style=")' at line 1. the ; breaks the sql

Comment: @AnnetteKennedy what version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: MariaDB 10.3.29-MariaDB

Comment: ok seems there is a way to change the Delimiter. so I changed it to * instead of  ; for this query and it worked fine as * does not break it if you use ; in your query. thanks for any help code that worked fine after changing the delimiter UPDATE oc_product_description SET description = REPLACE(description, '<br style="; ;">','')*